# run 2 build commands in a single docker run command

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, angular-cli, devops

I have to run maven and angular build inside a docker container with sh command as beolw:

```
docker run -v maven command and then ng build.
```

How to run/concatenate both commands in single docker run command?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is :

```
sh """
docker run -v ....\\
"maven command" \\
&& cd directory && ng build'
"""
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run multiple commands in docker, use /bin/bash -c with a semicolon ;
In this case, the second command **ng build** will be executed only if the first command (cd) returns no error or exit status. To avoid this use **&&** instead of **;** (semi-colon)

```
    docker run image /bin/bash -c "cd directory && ng build"
```

Comment: Yes exactly!! Thanks